# Why does my ".find" function give me erroneous values?

Tags: c++, string

I'm using the `.find` function to get a character position in order to do some string handling from lines which are read from a textfile. I feel that my implementation is correct but it gives me an unusable integer result. 
The
`#include <string>` header is used,
Code section is as follows:

```
ifstream IoTFile;
IoTFile.open("temp_data.txt");
if (IoTFile.is_open())
{
    while (!IoTFile.eof())
    {
        IoTFile >> sLine;
        int pos = sLine.find(",");
        cout << pos;
        //some irrelevant string handling...
    }
}
```

when I run the program, it does not give me any errors but the `pos` value is something like "1111111111111...." etc despite there being a "," comma at position 12. Any idea why this might be happening and how to solve it?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You seem to have enough information to create and post a [mcve].

Comment: Maybe that's a couple of 11's, if there are several lines with a "," at the same position?

Comment: What is the type of `sLine`? What is in the file that’s being read? Also, separate the output values with a space or a newline.

Comment: Can you add an example file?

Comment: **Always** verify that input was successful *after* trying to read! In this case use `while (IoTFile >> sLine) { ... }`

Comment: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: Zero based counting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code. Let me explain them one by one:

**(1) `find` is more efficient when it looks for a `char`**: Your code searches for a single comma character `,` so there is no need to pass a string as a parameter to the `find()` call. Using single quotes `','` instead of double quotes `","` will make your code more efficient:

```
sLine.find(',');
```

**(2) `find` doesn't return an `int`**: The `std::string::find()` method returns a `std::string::size_type` value. So calling the `find()` method should be like this:

```
std::string::size_type pos = sLine.find(',');
```

or you can simply use the `auto` keyword and let the compile find the right type for you

```
auto pos = sLine.find(',');
```

**(3) Check the result of `find`**: After you call `find()` you have to check if it found anything. You can do this by comparing the result with the `std::string::npos` value. If the values are equal, then it didn't find anything.

```
std::string::size_type pos = sLine.find(',');
if (pos != std::string::npos) {
    std::cout << pos;
}
```

**(4) Reading a file line by line**: it seems to me that you want to read a file line by line, but what your code does is actually read it word by word. This is why your `find()` calls are not working properly. If you want to read the file line by line, you can do this:

```
std::ifstream file("temp_data.txt");
if (file.is_open()) {
    std::string line;
    while (getline(file, line)) {
        std::string::size_type pos = line.find(',');
        // only print pos if the comma was found
        if (pos != std::string::npos) {
            std::cout << line << " - pos = " << pos << '\n';
        }
    }
    file.close();
}
```